# Calling a function from one class, from another

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables

I'm having a slight issue with ActionScript 3 and I have come here to ask for some help.

I have two classes. One called `Sledge` and one called `Sock`, there is also the document class called `Main`.

My issues are as follows:

- Inside of `Sledge`, I call a function that is defined inside of the `Main` document class. How would I go about telling the class to go to the document class and run that function? Would this also be the same for other classes or just for the document class?
- Inside `Sledge`, I have the following statement: `if(hitTestObject(sock.myHitArea)) { /* somecode*/ }`

  `sock` is an instance of another seperate class, and by this point has already been created. However when I try and run this I am told it is not defined. How would i go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some ambiguity issues with how you expressed your question. It would help if you posted a short form of the code for the problem.

However, I'll try to answer the first question:

> > Inside of Sledge, I call a function that is defined inside of the Main document class. How would I go about telling the class to go to the document class and run that function?

You would want to pass the Main class to the Sledge class or use events which is preferable. If pass the class it will look like this...

```
class Sledge {
   private var main:Main;
   function Sledge(main:Main) {
      this.main = main;
   }
   function doSomething():void {
     main.runSomeFunction();
   }
}
```

Or if using events:

```
class Main {
private var sledge:Sledge;
   function Main() {
      sledge = new Sledge();
      sledge.addEventListener("mainDoSomething", doSomething);
   }
   private function doSomething(e:Event):void {
     // .... do stuff
   }
}
class Sledge extends EventDispacter {
   function Sledge() {
   }
   public function doSomething():void {
     dispatchEvent(new Event("mainDoSomething"));
   }
}
```